# Power BI Slicer Default Selection

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, slicers

I have a PowerBI sheet consisting of multiple visuals and one slicer. The underlying data set includes one column called "selected" consiting of either "1" or "null". I want the slicer to always be default setted to only show data where the data entries in column "selected" are equal to "1". I want that the user is still possible to modify the selection and then be able to press a button to return to the pre-selection. I found no way possible to do this. Do you guys have any idea? I am pretty new to PowerBI.

I only found a way to pre-select the whole sheet or slicer to only show values where "selected" =1 but I want the user to be able to further select data. Also I only saw solutions for pre-selected slicer based on dates (e.g. most recent date is pre-selected).

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is to preselect all filter and save "bookmark" (view tab in powerbi desktop); Then you can assign a bookmark to the button.

Read this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/create-reports/desktop-bookmarks?tabs=powerbi-desktop

Comment: Thanks. But I dont know if that could work for me. The problem is, that the slicer does not include the column "selected". The slicer only allows the user to select by country. But I want the slicer to be pre selected with countries which are "selected"=1 but do not want to include this column in the slicer. Then I want the user to be able to select more countries, also those with selected="1", and press a button to get to default where selected="1" is pre-selected.

Comment: Also the countries with selected="1" will differ over time when new data is loaded, so the selection cannot base on the countries name but solely on the condition whether selected="1". So I cannot simply select all countries with selected="1" and then bookmark it.

Comment: Maybe you can add additional filter based on "selected" column. One slicer can affect another one;